# how i will add up the quantity if keys are same

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
Array
(


[INV828] => Array
    (
        [0] => shams interior
        [org_name] => shams interior
        [1] => INV828
        [inv_no] => INV828
        [2] => 1556
        [productid] => 1556
        [3] => E001-4ft
        [productname] => E001-4ft
        [4] => Paharganj
        [warehousename] => Paharganj
        [5] => 2018-04-19 16:55:05
        [date] => 2018-04-19 16:55:05
        [6] => 56
        [quantity_consumed] => 256
        [7] => 80364
        [invoiceid] => 80364
    )

[INV828] => Array
    (
        [0] => shams interior
        [org_name] => shams interior
        [1] => INV828
        [inv_no] => INV828
        [2] => 1556
        [productid] => 1556
        [3] => E001-4ft
        [productname] => E001-4ft
        [4] => Paharganj
        [warehousename] => Paharganj
        [5] => 2018-04-19 16:55:05
        [date] => 2018-04-19 16:55:05
        [6] => 56
        [quantity_consumed] => 56
        [7] => 80364
        [invoiceid] => 80364
    )

 )
```

i need to add the `[quantity_consumed]` where the key of the array `[INV828]` is same.i would like to add the `[quantity_consumed]` values that is 256+56 and make it one.

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in an array. You input data is wrong!

Comment: the array you showed is not possible at all, because same indexes got over-written.See what i said:- https://eval.in/1058897

Comment: the actual keys are [32] and [33] i have inserted the [inv_no] in place of the actual keys but i need to add [quantity_consumed] when [inv_no] are same

Comment: @Gaurav This looks like it is coming from an SQL query. Can you show your query instead? Maybe you won't need PHP at all for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an associative array with keys with the same value (e.g. [INV828]), the latest entry will overwrite the existing one.

For further information see: [PHP Manual Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

So your array will only have the following entry:

```
[INV828] => Array
(
    [0] => shams interior
    [org_name] => shams interior
    [1] => INV828
    [inv_no] => INV828
    [2] => 1556
    [productid] => 1556
    [3] => E001-4ft
    [productname] => E001-4ft
    [4] => Paharganj
    [warehousename] => Paharganj
    [5] => 2018-04-19 16:55:05
    [date] => 2018-04-19 16:55:05
    [6] => 56
    [quantity_consumed] => 56
    [7] => 80364
    [invoiceid] => 80364
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
$arr = array(
    array('org_name' => 'shams interior','inv_no' => 'INV828','productid' => 1556,'productname' => 'E001-4ft','warehousename' => 'Paharganj','date' => '2018-04-19 16:55:05','quantity_consumed' => 256,'invoiceid' => 80364),
    array('org_name' => 'shams interior','inv_no' => 'INV829','productid' => 1556,'productname' => 'E001-4ft','warehousename' => 'Paharganj','date' => '2018-04-19 16:55:05','quantity_consumed' => 256,'invoiceid' => 80364),
    array('org_name' => 'shams interior','inv_no' => 'INV828','productid' => 1556,'productname' => 'E001-4ft','warehousename' => 'Paharganj','date' => '2018-04-19 16:55:05','quantity_consumed' => 56,'invoiceid' => 80364),
    array('org_name' => 'shams interior','inv_no' => 'INV829','productid' => 1556,'productname' => 'E001-4ft','warehousename' => 'Paharganj','date' => '2018-04-19 16:55:05','quantity_consumed' => 256,'invoiceid' => 80364)
    );
$newArray = array();
foreach($arr as $k => $data) {
    if (array_key_exists($data['inv_no'], $newArray)) { // If inv_no key is already exists, then just add the consumed quantity
        $newArray[$data['inv_no']]['quantity_consumed'] = $newArray[$data['inv_no']]['quantity_consumed'] + $data['quantity_consumed'];
    } else { // else add the data as new inv_no key
        $newArray[$data['inv_no']] = $data;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
```

Output :-

```
Array
(
    [INV828] => Array
        (
            [org_name] => shams interior
            [inv_no] => INV828
            [productid] => 1556
            [productname] => E001-4ft
            [warehousename] => Paharganj
            [date] => 2018-04-19 16:55:05
            [quantity_consumed] => 312
            [invoiceid] => 80364
        )

    [INV829] => Array
        (
            [org_name] => shams interior
            [inv_no] => INV829
            [productid] => 1556
            [productname] => E001-4ft
            [warehousename] => Paharganj
            [date] => 2018-04-19 16:55:05
            [quantity_consumed] => 512
            [invoiceid] => 80364
        )

)
```